# npm publishing index.d.ts not export module

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, publishing, npm-publish

We are trying to create an npm package, that's the base for most of our projects,
but we're having some issues with the following:

the `index.d.ts` of our base npm package looks like the following:

```
export * from './src/core';

declare module '*.html' {
    const template: string;
    export default template;
}
```

the top line works great, we have access to our modules in the core folder,
however the second part, doesn't work.

but if we place the same code in `custom.d.ts` in our own project, the import for html files works great.

the  `package.json` (some parts are removed)  looks like following:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "dist/main.bundle.js",
  "module": "./index.js",
  "types": "./index.d.ts",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

folder structure:

```
app/
├── node_modules/
|   └── base/
│       ├── src/
│       |   └── core/
│       |       └── ....
│       └── index.d.ts
├── src/
│   └── ...
└── custom.d.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `import "base"` in the entry file of your project.
Otherwise TypeScript probably won't automatically include files under node_modules.

Comment: it is imported in our vendor.ts :)